# How to develop two Maven/Gradle projects in parallel?

Tags: maven, gradle, dependencies, repository

I am developing project `Product` and wishing to factor out it's part into separate project `Library`. I want `Library` to evolve in parallel with project, but stay separate. I have opened both projects in separate instances of `Idea`.

Currently I do in the following way.

My `Librariy`'s gradle files are following

```
group 'org.my.projects'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
...

rootProject.name = 'library'
```

and also contain code to publish to "local" Maven repository.

My `Product`'s gradle files are following

```
group 'org.my.projects'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
...

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    implementation group: 'org.my.projects', name: 'library', version: '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
...


rootProject.name = 'product'
```

It works but.

When I want to improve `Library` I need to

1. Change code of `Library`
2. Publish it local Maven repository
3. Go to `Product` code and sync it's Gradle deps

This is:

1. Slow. I can't just make a simple fix in `Library` and use it, I need to follow publish cycle instead.
2. Pollution of `Product`'s Gradle config: it contains reference to `mavenLocal()`.

Is there a way to develop two projects simultaneously?

Comment: Eclipse has a setting (which is activated by default) ☑ _Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects_. Doesn't have IntelliJ something similar?

Comment: You could make it one project with both Maven and Gradle files. Since your IDE probably handles Maven and Gradle differently, it is your choice which build system to identify the project with. Whichever you do not choose, you can execute from the command-line.